# How to detect different touch events on different image parts

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, swift

**Hello Community,**

I am a dev team leader. One of my great developers is working on a complicated app on iOS and Android. He is still facing an issue on how to develop one functionality. That's why I am asking here so that I can be of an assistnace to him.

In the below image, we want when the user touches/taps on a specific part of the sheeb, a new content should be retrieved from our backend via API.

**I have two questions:**

1. Should we have the below image be cut to more that one image file (each part is a separate image file) then we can bind them in code? Or is it better to keep it as one file?
2. Could you please refer me to any method, class, sample code, or any other resources on how to create similar funcationality on Android and iOS?

I appreciate it if you can refer me to similar code samples as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A neat "hack", if you want to get around splitting the image, is to simply overlay the image with other transparent or hidden objects such as buttons. These could simply overlay the names for example.

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution. Well, I am also looking for another soution because I want to highlight the touched part.

Comment: In that case you will need to split the image anyway as you can't independently highlight different sections of the image.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, my developer will go with your first suggestion without highlighting the touched part.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle it:
1) cut the image into pieces, add a listener to intercept the events, and display them so they look like one cohesive image.
2) Generate some polygons that mirror the image, add a single listener to the image to grab the touch location and cross reference the (x,y) of the with the polygons to determine which was clicked.

The first option is better since it would be easier to do things like color masks on touch.  You might also want to look into something SVGs for generating the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Create another bitmap as the same size of your main image and paint each area to a specific color. You can use 256 color (8 bit) or 16 color to keep memory usage as low as possible. Let's call this reference image. Keep a color = name list in your code. When user touch the image get the coordinate and find the color code of that coordinate in your reference image. Than find in your list which color is which part.

Also you can use this reference image to highlight specific part of your image.